# Is there any quick and direct way to find minimal polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there any elegant way to find minimal polynomial of a matrix like this:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 6 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

without having to explicitly find characteristic polynomial first by putting $|A-\lambda I|=0$ (and then estimate by trial and error, the minimal polynomial) ?

For larger matrices it gets really tedious to find minimal polynomial by trial and error.

Comment: Compute $I,A$ and see if they are linearly dependent. If not compute $A^2$ and see if they are now. If not compute $A^3$ and see if they are linearly dependent. If not it is the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @SphericalTriangle Justification? Also, matrix multiplication is computationally a pretty intensive task. By hand, too, calculating all those seems impractical. I was hoping there would be some geometric hack to this.

Comment: Matrix multiplication is as expensive as computing determinant.

Comment: Another way could be: Compute the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) of $A-\lambda I$. Compute the gcd of its entries. Divide the characteristic polynomial by this gcd. This might look to you simpler, even though it is just the same in terms of complexity. The previous one is self evident why it works. This one does require looking into the theory to see why it works.

Comment: @SphericalTriangle really not bad by hand.

Comment: @WillJagy However, the second method does compute the characteristic polynomial explicitly, and he didn't want to do that. The first method doesn't. The 'by hand' requirement was only added latter in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the question concerns block triangular matrices.
$$ A=\begin{bmatrix}B_1&B_2\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\mbox{ with }B_1=
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 6 & -1  \\ 0 & 1 & 3  \\ 0 & 3 & 1  \end{bmatrix},\ \ B_2=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix},$$
the "0" in the last row of $A$ actually being a row of 3 zeros. Then
$$B_1=\begin{bmatrix}2&C_1\\0&C_2\end{bmatrix}\mbox{ with } C_1=\begin{bmatrix}6&-1\end{bmatrix},C_2=\begin{bmatrix}1&3\\3&1\end{bmatrix}.$$
As a first observation, the characteristic polynomial is easily deduced: $\det(\lambda I-A)=(\lambda-1)\det(\lambda I-B_1)=(\lambda-1)(\lambda-2)\det(\lambda I-C_2)=(\lambda-1)(\lambda-2)((\lambda -1)^2-9)$.
As a consequence, the eigenvalues are $1,2,1\pm3$. Since they are distinct, the matrix A is diagonalisable and the characteristic polynomial is its minimal polynomial.
This seems elegant enough to treat the example presented, but what to do if, for example $C_2=\begin{bmatrix}-1&3\\3&-1\end{bmatrix}$ and hence the eigenvalues are $1,2, -4$, where $2$ has (algebraic) multiplicity 2?
The corresponding $B_1=
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 6 & -1  \\ 0 & -1 & 3  \\ 0 & 3 & -1  \end{bmatrix}$
has an eigenspace of dimension 1 corresponding to the eigenvalue 2 and so its minimal polynomial is $(\lambda-2)^2(\lambda+4)$. As $B_1$ does not have the eigenvalue 1, $A$ is conjugate to $A=\begin{bmatrix}B_1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and hence has minimal polynomial $(\lambda-2)^2(\lambda+4)(\lambda-1)$.
As another example, consider $A$ with submatrix $B_1$ replaced by $B_1=
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & -1  \\ 0 & -1 & 3  \\ 0 & 3 & -1  \end{bmatrix}$. Then the eigenspace of the eigenvalue 2 has dimension 2 and the minimal polynomial of $B_1$ is $(\lambda-2)(\lambda+4)$. Proceeding as before, the minimal polynomial of $A$ is then $(\lambda-2)(\lambda+4)(\lambda-1)$.
From the examples, it can be seen how to proceed in general for block triangular matrices such that one diagonal block consists of one element: Consider a matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}B_1&B_2\\0&a\end{bmatrix}$, $a$ a scalar and suppose that $B_1$ has the minimal polynomial $m(\lambda)$.
If $a$ is not a zero of $m(\lambda)$ then $A$ is conjugate to $\begin{bmatrix}B_1&0\\0&a\end{bmatrix}$ and has minimal polynomial $m(\lambda)(\lambda-a)$.
If $a$ is a zero of $m(\lambda)$, then consider the highest power $(\lambda-a)^m$ of $\lambda-a$ dividing $m(\lambda)$. This means that $m$ is the smallest integer such that the dimension of the kernel of $(B_1-a I)^m$ equals the algebraic multiplicity of $a$ as a zero of the characteristic polynamial of $B_1$. Calculate 
$$(A-a I)^m=\begin{bmatrix}(B_1-a I)^m&(B_1-a I)^{m-1}B_2\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$
If the ranks of $(B_1-a I)^m$ and $\begin{bmatrix}(B_1-a I)^m&(B_1-a I)^{m-1}B_2\end{bmatrix}$ do not agree, then the dimension of the kernel of $(A-a I)^m$ is equal to that of the kernel of $(B_1-a I)^m$, because $ (B_1-a I)^{m-1}B_2$ is not in the image of $(B_1-a I)^m$. Therefore it is smaller than the algebraic multiplicity of $a$ in the characteristic polynomial of $A$ (actually by 1). Hence the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $m(\lambda)(\lambda-a)$.
If the two ranks agree, then the dimension of the kernel of $(A-a I)^m$ equals the multiplicity of $a$ in the characteristic polynomial of $A$ and $m(\lambda)$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$.
Actually, the important information is that the minimal polynomial of $A$ can only be equal to $m(\lambda)$ or $m(\lambda)(\lambda-a)$. Therefore it is also sufficient to check if $m(A)$ is zero or not.
This method of treating block triangular matrices where one block is scalar is maybe not elegant, but I do not know any better.

Answer (score 1):

lots of zeroes. Determinant of $A - \lambda I$ is
$$ (2 - \lambda) \left( (1- \lambda)^3 - 9 (1-\lambda)\right) \; ,  $$
$$ (2 - \lambda)(1 - \lambda) \left( (1- \lambda)^2 - 9 \right) $$
$$ (2 - \lambda)(1 - \lambda) \left(  \lambda^2 - 2 \lambda - 8 \right) $$
$$ (2 - \lambda)(1 - \lambda)(\lambda - 4)(\lambda + 2) $$